# USB Ethernet adapter - device mixing up with charging

Tags: usb, ethernet

I have USB-C to Ethernet adapter for my Android (Samsung S21 Ultra)

when I plug cable in it detects it and the connection is fine, but after some time (few minutes). Connection drops.

Then it shows that "charging cable is connected" my impression is that it is confusing with charging and switching the modes (between charging and that Ethernet one).

Is there any way to stabilize this? I tried a few things

1. shorter cables
2. use 100% charged phone
3. turn wifi/mobile connections off

the result is the same, unstable connection

P.S: I also cannot assign static IP, The form is there and I am filling it up but the Save button is grayed  out so my only option is DHCP

Edit: this is happening with 2 different USB devices (one is simple USBC-C to Ethernet, another one is Belkin dongle) behavior is exactly the same. This is also happening with 2 different routers. *This should exclude those factors*

Comment: check logcat for hints what's going on